Can' Access Environmental Variables from .env in NextJS project
I am doing a project using NextJS and Firebase Auth. But while Initializing Firebase I tried giving the api key as process.env.KEY. But apparently it is not working.
.env
FIREBASE_API_KEY = "<KEY>"

Firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    //config..
  };

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Is there anything more I should do in NextJS?
I Even tried console printing process.env.KEY
But it also gives an error.
console.log(process.env.KEY);


As mentioned in their documentation you can take advantage of @next/env package
